# Proxy some api calls to a third party in rails-api

Tags: ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-4, proxy

I have a collection of API endpoints. One of the endpoints is supposed to load some content from another server. I'm using rails-api for the API server.

Essentially the api call needs to do the following:

```
api_call --> api_server --> GET thirdparty_server.com
```

the api_server then needs to return whatever is provided by thirdparty_server.com. Is this doable in rails? Essentially, we don't want the thirdparty_server accessible to anything else except the rails api.

We want the content from thirdparty_server.com to be loaded into an iframe on the client side.To give more context:

```
iframe           --> api             --> thirdparty --> api --> iframe
src="api_call_url"   GET thidparty_url   Resp       --> Resp--> Resp
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is easy in Rails. I suggest using [HTTParty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty).

You can set up a `Proxy` controller. Here is a simplified example:

```
def request
  external_request = HTTParty.get(thirdparty_url) 
  external_request.body
end
```

You would map `api_call_url` to `proxy/request`.